# How to apply some validations in a column in Propel schema?

Tags: xsd, schema, propel, symfony-2.5, symfony-2.6

I am using Propel schema to create database tables. In a table, i need to create a 'name' column which should hold a 'short string', 'all in lower case', and 'with no spaces', for example:
'join', 'appointment'.

How can I define this column in schema.xml with given constraints? Or do I have to create a custom validator to get it done?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [validate behaviour](http://propelorm.org/documentation/behaviors/validate.html) in your schema.xml.

There are several validators to choose from, you would probably use the [Choice Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html).

Example:

```
<table name='TableName'>
  ...
  <column name='name' type='varchar' size='20' />
  <behavior name="validate">
    <parameter name="rule1" value="{column: name, validator: Choice, options: {message: Please enter a valid name }}" />
  </behavior>
</table>
```